# How to set environment variables for build task in IntelliJ Rust?

Tags: rust, clion

In Rust 1.52.1 incremental compilation is disabled, but I want to enable it because it speeds up my compilation time by 3 times.
There are `RUSTC_FORCE_INCREMENTAL` environmental variable for it. So I want to set `RUSTC_FORCE_INCREMENTAL=1` for build task, but it seems CLion doesn't support that. I can only set environmental variables for Run Configurations.

Comment: incremental compilation is fixed in 1.52.1, so consider updating if possible!

Comment: @njha Sorry, I meant 1.52.1. In this version incremental compilation is just disabled. You cannot enable it in cargo config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html): place a `build.rs` file in the root of your package and use `cargo:rustc-env=VAR=VALUE` instruction:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=RUSTC_FORCE_INCREMENTAL=1");
}
```